# Stream object that handles numbers

Tags: c++, stl, stream, bytestream

This may be a very basic question but while digging through STL reference I can't find anything suitable. As an example

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "One hundred and one: " << 101;
```

would result in `One hundred and one: 101` stored in `oss`, means the numeric value `101` is converted to text. What I'm looking for is a stream object that keeps the numeric value so that something like:

```
numstream nums;
nums << 10 << 0 << 15;
```

would result in a byte or string buffer containing not a textual representation of `10`, `0` and `15` but just these three numbers.

Any idea what could be used for this?

Comment: sounds like you could use `vector<int>` to store the data first.

Comment: See [Boost.Assign](http://www.boost.org/libs/assign/) for a library allowing shorthand insertion into a vector.

Comment: Why exactly do you want that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A buffer containing a sequence of integers is what `std::vector<int>`
controls.

You can override the global operator `<<` to append
any type `T` to any container type `C` for which such an operation is
meaningful:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<int> & operator<<(std::vector<int> & vi, int i)
{
    vi.push_back(i);
    return vi;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vi;
    vi << 1 << 2 << 3;
    for(auto i : vi) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, if *all* you want to achieve is an abbreviation of, e.g.

```
si.push_back(i);
```

for some integer sequence `si` and int `i`, and to be able to shorten, e.g.

```
si.push_back(i);
si.push_back(j);
si.push_back(k);
```

to:

```
si << i << j << k;
```

remember that the brevity you gain comes at the cost of
making otherwise skilled readers research what your abbreviations are - 
and how safe they are.

I suggest that shortening `si.push_back(i)` to `si << i` is not worthwhile
and that if you want to get tiresomely long sequences of `push_back(n)` onto
one line then it would be sufficient and less eccentric to define
a type-safe variadic function template for the purpose, e.g.

```
void push_back(std::vector<int> & vi){}

template<typename ...Ts>
void push_back(std::vector<int> & vi, int i, Ts... ts)
{
    vi.push_back(i);
    if (sizeof...(Ts)) {
        push_back(vi,ts...);
    }
}
```

With which you would write, e.g.

```
push_back(si,i,j,k);
```

rather than:

```
si << i << j << k;
```

Answer (score 0):

With this semantic (stream insertion): no there isn't.

From your example it looks like you want to fill a vector of integers with integers.

You will need a functor (ostream manipulator) which would translate the ostream-like semantics into vector-element-addition.

Something along the lines of:

```
struct functor {
   functor(std::vector<int>& viref):
      myVector(viref)
   {}
   // this operator overload translates stream-insert operator
   // into vector element addition
   functor& operator<<(const int i) {
      myVector.push_back(i);
      return *this;
   }
   std::vector<int>& myVector;
};

int main() {
   std::vector<int>   vi;
   functor            f( vi );

   f << 1 << 2 << 3;
}
```

Alternatively, you could always write your own streambuffer class (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/) but I doubt that that will go down very well because the whole string/stream buf mechanism really is meant to be dealing with single characters being inserted/removed.